# How to display the data in the tableview according to the api

Tags: swift, tableview

I have `tableView`.

```
class DataModel: Mappable {

    var name: String = ""

    var geoArray = [DataModel]()

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {

        name <- map["name"]


        dataFetched : for i in 0...100{

            array <- map["Add\(i)"]


            if  array.count > 0{

                break dataFetched
            }

        }

    }

}
```

in `viewController`:-

```
var ListArray = [DataModel]()

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.ListArray.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)


    cell.textLabel?.text = self.ListArray[indexPath.row].name
    return cell
}
```

my api is as this format :-

```
"Add": [{"name":"Topics","Add1":[{"name":"Subjects","Add2":[{"name":"Biology","Add3":[{and so.......}]}]}]}]
```

so i need the output as :-

```
 Topics
 Subjects
 Biology
 ......
```

this way i need to display in the tableview.What changes need to do .How to get the solution

i have used api to pass the data as :-

```
    func  getData()  {

    let url = "example.com"
    print(url)

    self.newtworkHelper.makeAPIRequestget(url: url, needHeaders:true, successCompletion: { (data, isError, isNetworkError,isGoToLogin) in

        print(data)
        print(isError)
        print(isNetworkError)
        print(isGoToLogin)

        if isNetworkError{

            print("network error")

            return
        }

        if isGoToLogin{

            print("isgologin")

            return
        }

        if isError{

            print("error")
            return
        }

        if let response = data as? [String:Any]{

        if let result = response["result"] as? [String:Any]{

            if let Add = result["Add"] as? [[String : Any]]{

                for request in Add {

                    self.ListArray.append(DataModel(JSON: request)!)


                }
            }

          }}

        self.tableview.reloadData()

    })

}
```

Comment: how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a data model class
   *I think you already did*
2. Create a model array
   *You did it also*
3. Parse Json, init data, add instances to your array
   *I couldn't see how you parse your data, and initialize your datamodel instances*
4. init your table data with TableViewDataSourceDelegate, with using your array
   *At this point actually I'd prefer to see your cell model, I don't know how you to customize it*

That's usually my solution. I hope it helps.

Comment: i have added my code please check...how to solve this issues

Comment: Can you debug your code, what is in your array before tableView.reloadData() is called. Maybe you are reloading your table view before api call didn't finish and your array is not initialized.. If it is the case, you can check completion blocks

Comment: i checked .i have called the function getdata() in the self.viewDidLoad of view controller .But i getting the first name only .I need to display the whole name in the tableview.How to implement

Comment: how to implement this?

Comment: I think I don't understand your last question.. What's the type of the whole name.. Isn't that a string ?

Comment: So since you are not trim the string you would be able to get the whole name afaik I know.

Comment: i need to display the name from the model .how to disply

Comment: cell.yourNameVar = yourDataModel.name

Comment: what should give in the cellfortableview and numberofrows in tableview

Comment: I do not know what is your custom view cell variables.. Let say this you have a name label..
 yourNameLabel?.text! = self.ListArray[indexPath.row].name
If your name consist of new line command be sure that your label lines is appropriate to your input

Comment: if i give the code as yourNameLabel?.text! = self.ListArray[indexPath.row].name the output will display as:Topics. The other names will not display.How to display that names

Comment: how to implement?